# Mint 17.3: Your session has lasted less than 10 seconds

Tags: linux-mint, login, error-handling

yesterday I executed 'sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'
and today I get the following error after the login

```
Your session has lasted less than 10 seconds...
syndaemon: no process found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
localuser:gauss being added to access control list
Script for none started at run_im.
Segmentation fault
Script for none started at run_im.
mate-session[2167]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
mate-session[2167]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

 So Jul 03$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: gauss-PC Kernel: 4.4.0-28-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 4.8.4)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.0.6 (Gtk 3.10.8~8+qiana) Distro: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: P5Q-PRO v: Rev 1.xx Bios: American Megatrends v: 0703 date: 06/12/2008
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 Duo E8400 (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11999
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 2667 MHz 2: 2667 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV770 [Radeon HD 4850] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.15.1 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1920x1080@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
           GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV770 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4850/4870]
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Card-2 Intel 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-28-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
           driver: ATL1E port: dc00 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: 00:22:15:12:4a:96
           Card-2: AVM Fritz!WLAN N 2.4 [Atheros AR9001U] driver: carl9170 usb-ID: 002-002
           IF: wlan0 state: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 320.1GB (43.7% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_HD322HJ size: 320.1GB temp: 24C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 20G used: 9.0G (48%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-2: /home size: 33G used: 18G (57%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda9
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 55.0C mobo: 40.0C gpu: 76.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 1125 psu: 843 sys-1: 888 sys-2: 763
Info:      Processes: 204 Uptime: 11 min Memory: 882.7/4036.7MB Init: Upstart runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.111) inxi: 2.2.28
```

When I enter tty1 mode (Ctrl-Alt-F2) at the login, I use 'startx' but then the software rendering mode is active so that the system is very slow.
When I use 'startx' as root the software rendering mode is not active.

Also using cinnamon did not helped.

Thx for any help